# where does spring jpa repository store data?

Tags: java, spring, jpa, repository

Does it store it in cache? I have an application and nowhere in the application.properties are db details mentioned. I am able to store data and query it via Postman.

Comment: Then you're probably using Spring Boot with an in-memory database. https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/htmlsingle/#boot-features-embedded-database-support

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Spring boot Jpa: hibernate as default?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41902856/spring-boot-jpa-hibernate-as-default)

Comment: @DV82XL The fact it uses Hibernate does not answer **where** it stores the data.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Spring Boot uses auto-configuration to configure persistence based on what dependencies are present on the class path. For example, If you provide a dependency to `spring-boot-starter-data-jpa` in `pom.xml` with no other config, `JPA/Hibernate` uses an in-memory `H2` database by default. You can make this explicit by adding the following to `application.properties`:

```
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:h2:mem:testdb
spring.data.jpa.repositories.bootstrap-mode=default
spring.datasource.driverClassName=org.h2.Driver
spring.jpa.database-platform=org.hibernate.dialect.H2Dialect
```

By default, the contents of the in-memory `H2` database are stored in volatile memory, so will be lost when your application terminates. You can store data to a local file by adding this to `application.properties`:

```
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:h2:file:/path/to/my/data
```

To view the contents of the `H2` database in a console, add the following to `application.properties` and go to http://localhost:8080/h2-console :

```
spring.h2.console.enabled=true
```